# como posicionar div frente a todas la imagenes del slideshow?

Tags: php, html, css, html5, css3

estoy cargando imagenes dinamicas alojadas en una carpeta para poblar un slideshow, hasta aqui todo bien.
Ahora intento poner un reloj en la esquina superior derecheca, pongo el div pero el reloj me queda fuera del div en color negro y solo me aparece en la primer imagen que se carga, es todas las demas solo aparecen los dos puntos que separan las horas y los minutos.

Este es el Css:

```
.wrap{
background:rgba(0,0,0,10);
position: absolute;
padding:50px;
width:50%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 70%;
margin: 0, auto;
color:#ffff;
/*max-width: 100px; */
/*margin:auto;*/
}
.widget{
/*background:rgba(0,0,0,);*/
width: 90%;
margin: 0;
display: block;
}

.widget p{

display: inline-block;
line-height: 1em;
 }
 .reloj{
position:absolute;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
width: 50%;
height: 10px;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
background:rgb(0,0,0,0);
}

.reloj .caja-segundos{
display: inline-block;

}
 .reloj .segundos,
 .reloj .ampm{

font-size: 2rem;
display: block;
}
```

y este es el archivo .php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<title>Floor presentation</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superslides.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>

    <div id="slides">
    
    <?php
  $files = scandir("img/");
    
?>
  <ul class="slides-container">
  <?php
    $a=0;
    for ($i=2; $i < count($files) ; $i++):
    
  ?>
    <li class="item <?php echo $a == 0 ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
      <img src="img/<?php echo $files[$i]; ?>" alt="">
      
      <div class="wrap">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="reloj">
    <p id="horas" class="horas"></p>
    <p>:</p>
    <p id="minutos" class="minutos"></p>
    <p>:</p>
    <div class="caja-segundos">
      <p id="ampm" class="ampm"></p>
      <p id="segundos" class="segundos"></p>
    </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <?php
    $a++;
  endfor;
  ?>
    
  </ul>
  <nav class="slides-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
    <a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.superslides.js"></script>
<script src="js/reloj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Asi es como se ve en la primer imagen que se carga, el reloj quiero que este dentro del div en color negro pero no se como posicionarlo ahi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en las demas imagenes solo se cargan los separadores de horas y minutos asi como en la imagen,ni siquiera se muestra la hora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pueden ayudarme a poner la hora dentro del div en la esquina superior derecha y que ese div con el reloj se superponga frente a todas las imagenes del slideshow??

Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué clase tiene el div en el cual quieres sobre poner el reloj?

Comment: @BetaM lo quiero poner dentro del class que se llama wrap y a su vez ese div superponerlo frente a todas las imagenes

Comment: el reloj lo hice siguiendo este tutorial de falconmaster https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IowfM4bkyb8

Comment: Necesitamos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, ya que tu galería se llena de forma dinámica con una base de datos; por favor trata de armar un ejemplo pequeño que nos ayude a entender mejor tu escenario

Comment: Saludos. Te falta declara en el CSS "horas" y "minuto" puede estos esten generando ese efecto (los demas si están); ahora, prueba en un div poner dentro de este lo del reloj y lo del slideshow; es decir no colocar el reloj dentro del cada <li>; espero se entienda mi sugerencia

Comment: @BetaM solo necesito un ejemplo, independientemente si es con un reloj o no, puede ser con texto yo lo puedo adaptar a mi necesidad, solo quiero poder guiarme de algun ejemplo veridico

Comment: @RobertoLeOr no entendi tu comentario, si pudieras explicarlo un poco mas, me es complicado entender el css

Answer (score 0):

Prueba coloca `slide` y `widget` (que entiendo este es el que tiene el reloj) en el mismo nivel. Es decir:

```
<div class="content"> <!-- Este seria el contenedor principal -->
   <div class="widget"><div class="reloj"><!-- todo lo del reloj --></div></div>
   <div id="slides"><!-- todo lo del slides; sin repetir reloj--></div>
</div>
```

Veo en tu `for ($i=2; $i < count($files) ; $i++):` tiene incluido se cree lo de **reloj**; seria quitarlo de allí ya que como puedes observar estaría afuera. Ahora desde luego será le pongas o te cerciores ya tiene definido en el CSS lo que le permitira esta arriba, a la derecha, fijo, etc...; y claro que el slide se comporta normalmente; si por alguna razón reloj se muestra atras de slide agrega propiedad `z-index` a div widget por ejemplo con valor de 1000 (mil) o más: `z-index="1000"`.

Comment: solamente logre posicionar el reloj en el lugar que quiero, pero solo aparece en la primer imagen en todas las demas sigue apareciendo solo los dos puntos separadores y el div en color negro pero no aparecen la hora como en la primer imagen